# Use flutter plugin using swift in flutter project with !use_frameworks?

Tags: swift, flutter

Is it possible to use a flutter plugin that is using swift as the iOs language, even though apparently there are some problems using swift when !use_frameworks is commented out in the podfile?

I couldn't find any good documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're running up against https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10968

It's not working at the moment, though there's some recent discussion the issue, so stay tuned.

Comment: Yeah, I think I kinda resurrected the whole issue yesterday :-). Since I need a solution now, I'll probably have to resort to re-writing my plugins in objective-c for now :-/.